# appengine many to many field update value and lookup efficiently

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am using appengine with python 2.7 and webapp2 framework. I am **not** using ndb.model.

I have the following model:

```
class Story(db.Model);
    name = db.StringProperty()

class UserProfile(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    user = db.UserProperty()

class Tracking(db.Model):
   user_profile = db.ReferenceProperty(UserProfile)
   story = db.ReferenceProperty(Story)
   upvoted = db.BooleanProperty()
   flagged = db.BoolenProperty()
```

A user can upvote and/or flag a story but only once. Hence I came up with the above model.
Now when a user clicks on the `upvote` link, on the database I try to see if the user has not already voted it, hence I do try to do the following:

1. get the user instance with his id as `up = db.get(db.Key.from_path('UserProfile', uid))`
2. then get the story instance as follows `s_ins = db.get(db.Key.from_path('Story', uid))`
3. Now it is the turn to check if a `Tracking` based on these two exist, if **yes** then don't allow voting, else allow him to vote and **update the Tracking** instance.

What is the most convenient way to **fetch** a `Tracking` instance given an id(`db.key().id()`) of `user_profile` and `story`?

What is the most convenient way to **save** a `Tracking` model having given a user profile id and an story id?

Is there a better way to implement tracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try tracking using lists of keys versus having a separate entry for track/user/story:

```
class Story(db.Model);
  name = db.StringProperty()

class UserProfile(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  user = db.UserProperty()

class Tracking(db.Model):
  story = db.ReferenceProperty(Story)
  upvoted = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
  flagged = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

So when you want to see if a user upvoted for a given story:

```
Tracking.all().filter('story =', db.Key.from_path('Story', uid)).filter('upvoted =', db.Key.from_path('UserProfile', uid)).get(keys_only=True)
```

Now the only problem here is the size of the upvoted/flagged lists can't grow too large (I think the limit is 5000), so you'd have to make a class to manage this (that is, when adding to the upvoted/flagged lists, detect if X entries exists, and if so, start a new tracking object to hold additional values). You will also have to make this transactional and with HR you have a 1 write per second threshold. This may or may not be an issue depending on your expected use case. A way around the write threshold would be to implement upvotes/flags using pull-queues and to have a cron job that pulls and batch updates tracking objects as needed.

This method has its pros/cons. The most obvious cons are the ones I just listed. The pros, however, may be worth it. You can get a full list of users who upvoted/flagged a story from a single list (or multiple depending on how popular the story is). You can get a full list of users with a lot fewer queries to the datastore. This method should also take less storage, index, and metadata space. Additionally, adding a user to a tracking object will be cheaper, instead of writing a new object + 2 writes for each property, you would just be charged 1 write for the object + 2 writes for the entry to the list (9 vs 3 writes for adding users to a pre-existing tracked story, or 9 vs 7 for untracked stories)

Answer (score 0):

What you propose sounds reasonable.

Don't use the app engine generated key for Tracking.  Because the combination of story/user should be unique, create your own key as a combination of the story/user.  Something like

```
tracking = Tracking.get_or_insert(str(story.id) + "-" + str(user.id), **params)
```

If you know the story/user, then you can always fetch the tracking by key name.

Comment: could u please elaborate on (str(story.id) + "-" + `str(user.id), **params)`

Comment: you can use any arbitrary string, so just create one by appending the userids together, ie "1234-890123".  Check the docs for get_or_insert() for the params (and you also need to verify whether a new entity was created, or whether the fetch succeeded).